# How to loop through HTML5 multiple file upload?

Tags: php, html

I have used the form below to upload multiple images to my server.

```
<form name="addimageForm" id="addimageForm" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">              
    Gallery Image: 
    <input name="image_name[]" type="file" id="image_name" multiple="true">
    <input type="submit" name="addCatImage"/>
</form>
```

But I am confused how I should loop through it so that I can insert multiple images in my database. I used the code below, and when I run it, even when I select a image, 4 rows are inserted in my table. I think it is inserting all of the array fields(name, size, tmp_name). How can i solve the problem?

```
foreach ($_FILES[image_name] as $file) {
    $access->uploadSubCatImages();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_FILES is multidimensional. With the syntax that you used, the Filenames would be accessible in

```
$_FILES['image_name']['name'][0] # for the first one
$_FILES['image_name']['name'][1] # for the second one
```

and so on.
Here is a link for reference [Uploading Multiple Files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Answer (score 1):

PHP makes the attributes themselves arrays. Yeah, I don't know who decided that.

```
// PHP does this:
$_FILES['image_name']['name'] = array('file1', 'file2', 'file'3);
$_FILES['image_name']['type'] = array('...', ...);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 0):

First, the index to the $_FILES array is a **string**. Although will PHP 'eat' it and just throw a E_NOTICE, you should not do it. Use `'image_name'` instead. (note the quotes)

Also the array structure may be different from what you've exptected. The following will loop trough the filen ames for example:

```
foreach ($_FILES['image_name']['name'] as $filename) {
    // do work here
}
```

Please refer to the documentation on [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) and especially [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) doc page.

Comment: FYI, unquoted identifiers are interpreted as strings by PHP, with an E_NOTICE.

Comment: @Rygu To be more specific, they're considered undefined constants, and PHP handles the error by interpreting the constant name as its value. This may change in a future version, so you should *not* rely on this.

Comment: @AgentConundrum Thanks for the precise explanation. Indeed, one should not rely on it.